# How to show Piechart in Panel in Winform

Tags: c#, winforms, charts, panel, pie-chart

I am creating Piechart in winform.My chart is coming fine.The only thing that i want to add up is to display the Piechart in Panel but i am not able to do it..

Here is the Code of Piechart..

```
    public void DrawPieChartOnForm()
    {
        //Take Total Five Values & Draw Chart Of These Values.
        int[] myPiePercent = { 10, 20, 25, 5, 40 };

        //Take Colors To Display Pie In That Colors Of Taken Five Values.
        Color[] myPieColors = { Color.Red, Color.Black, Color.Blue, Color.Green, Color.Maroon };

        using (Graphics myPieGraphic = this.CreateGraphics())
        {
            //Give Location Which Will Display Chart At That Location.
            Point myPieLocation = new Point(10, 400);

            //Set Here Size Of The ChartÃ¢â‚¬Â¦
            Size myPieSize = new Size(500, 500);

            //Call Function Which Will Draw Pie of Values.
            DrawPieChart(myPiePercent, myPieColors, myPieGraphic, myPieLocation, myPieSize);
        }
    }
```

Please help me..
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to understand the basics of WinForms Graphics.

To put your pie onto a `Panel` instead of the `Form`, as you have it now, you only need to change the `this.CreateGraphics()` to `panel.CreateGraphics()`. **But that is no good!** Your pie dissappears when you minimize your Form, right..?

So, **all** drawing must happen/be triggered from a `Paint` event, using its `e.Graphics` object! 
Only in this way will the drawing persist all sorts of outside events.

You can store the data at class level and call the `DrawPieChart` in the `Paint` event of the `Panel`, handing in `e.Graphics` instead of `myPieGraphic`.. Use `panel.Invalidate()` to trigger the paint event whenever you have changed the values..:

```
//Five Values at class level
int[] myPiePercent = { 10, 20, 25, 5, 40 };

//Take Colors To Display Pie In That Colors Of Taken Five Values.
Color[] myPieColors = { Color.Red, Color.Black, Color.Blue, Color.Green, Color.Maroon };


public void DrawPieChart()
{
    // maybe change the values here..
    myPiePercent = { 11, 22, 23, 15, 29 };
    // then let Paint call the draw routine:
    panel1.Invalidate();

}

private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{

   //Give Location Which Will Display Chart At That Location.
   Point myPieLocation = new Point(10, 400);

   //Set Size Of The Chart
   Size myPieSize = new Size(500, 500);

   //Call Function Which Will Draw Pie of Values.
   DrawPieChart(myPiePercent, myPieColors, e.Graphics, myPieLocation, myPieSize);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this article by Hiren Khirsaria:

[hirenkhirsaria.blogspot.com/2012/06/dynamically-creating-piebar-chart-in-c.html](http://hirenkhirsaria.blogspot.com/2012/06/dynamically-creating-piebar-chart-in-c.html)

---

i think what you need todo was to create a control to handle for piechart and just add it on panel .
Something like:

```
panel.Controls.Add(pieChart);
```